# How to increase GIT Post Size?

Tags: git

I'm using the command: `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` through SourceTree's terminal, but it's not doing anything, no errors either. I enter it and it just goes to a new line as if nothing happened.

How can I get it to work?

Comment: You are setting a config value, and you don't get an error, so the setting succeeded. That is normal command-line-tool behavior: no message means success, you get an error message if an error occurs. You can verify the success by either reading the value back with `git config http.postBuffer` or by examining the file `.git/config` in your repository.

Answer (score 1):

You do this

```
git config --global http.postBuffer your_prefer_post_size
```

For example:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Comment: Is the command supposed to give feedback of any kind? Because every time I try it, it goes to a new line. Which leads me to believe it's not accepting it.

Comment: In your case, you shouldn't use GUI, try to use command line.

Comment: Sorry, I'm so new to this. I've been using the SourceTree terminal (Git Bash). Should I be using that?

Comment: @BlueberryBandit, git config does not return anything when it is successful.

Comment: I see, thanks. Wish it would as it's hard to initially tell whether it's really working.

Comment: difference between git config & git config --global is that without --global you need to run that command within the directory structure of the repo itself. With --global flag you are essentially setting the post size for all of your clones.